# Orphan Event Receivers SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

For some reason my feature event receiver still runs after deactivation and uninstall. I have an feature event receiver on my SharePoint 2010 server that runs on a survey list prevent users to delete survey responses. If I deactivated the feature event receiver, I still can't delete responses. Even after I did an uninstall and iisreset, the event receiver was still running. My solution was to run a powershell command that will physically remove the event receiver from the survey list. Once I did that, I was able to delete survey responses from an existing survey. Any idea why even after an deactivation and uninstall I still have an attached event receiver to my survey list?

Answer (score 1):

If you added the Event Receiver to a list in FeatureActivated, you should remove it from that list in FeatureDeactivating.

Comment: But it applies to any survey add to the site. So if I have 50 surveys for one site, the event reciever will run for all 50 surveys...

Comment: What kind of Event Receiver is this: List or Content Type? Also, how was it added: element XML or code? If it was added by code, it needs to be removed by code.